# The Row Added Disappears when Clicking or Selecting a cell in The DaTagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell

I Add a Row To Dgw for The Sum off Columns , But When I click On Dgw Or Select a cell The Row Disappear.

I am Using an Sqlite Database.

This Is the code:

```
    Private Sub ComboPontes_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboPontes.SelectionChangeCommitted

    Dim dbPonte As LaPonte = CType(ComboPontes.SelectedItem, LaPonte)
    Dim dt = Opst.NetSevragesByPonte(dbPonte.PonteID)
    If dbPonte.PonteID > -1 Then
        _bsSEVPonte1.DataSource = dt
        Dgd1.DataSource = _bsSEVPonte1
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In Dgd1.Columns
            column.HeaderText = column.HeaderText.SplitCamelCase()
        Next
        Dgd1.ExpandColumns()

        Dim Sum As Integer = 0
        Dim Sum1 As Integer = 0
        ' Sum
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Sum += If(Not Convert.IsDBNull(Dgd1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value), Convert.ToInt32(Dgd1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value), 0)
            Sum1 += If(Not Convert.IsDBNull(Dgd1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value), Convert.ToInt32(Dgd1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value), 0)
        Next
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            col.[ReadOnly] = False
        Next
        Dgd1("Race", Dgd1.Rows.Count - 1).Value = "TOTAL"
        Dgd1("OiseauxSevrés", Dgd1.Rows.Count - 1).Value = Sum
        Dgd1("NetOiseauxSevrés", Dgd1.Rows.Count - 1).Value = Sum1
```

end sub

Thank you verty Much.

Comment: It is difficult to see what you are doing here. You are setting up a 'LaPonte' type, which I can't find any mention of, then you are resetting the datagrid to a datatable(?) which is in a separate class, then you reset the datasource of the LaPonte item before doing any work. Any more information would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
Dgd1("Race", Dgd1.Rows.Count - 1).Value = "TOTAL"
Dgd1("OiseauxSevrés", Dgd1.Rows.Count - 1).Value = Sum
("NetOiseauxSevrés", Dgd1.Rows.Count - 1).Value = Sum1
```

Your datagridview seems to be bound to a **datatable**, but here you are trying to update the grid directly instead. So your changes don't stick.
What you should do is update the datatable or better yet, you could use a [bindingsource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.8).

To add a new row you could do like this:

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
With dr
    .Item("Field1") = "Value1"
    .Item("Field2") = "Value2"
    .Item("Field3") = "Value3"
End With
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

Or event shorter: add values for each field in the row:

```
dt.Rows.Add("Value1", "Value2", "Value3")
```

But the user could click on the columns to change the sort order, or even drag the columns to change their position. So you may need to devise some trick to preserve the desired layout. Could be a hidden sort key or something else. *I would probably keep sub totals out of the datagrid though*. Why not use labels or the status bar at the bottom of your form ?

I would just recalculate the subtotals when the underlying data changes. For example you could perform the calculations using the [Compute function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.8).

In case you are trying to sum columns, the [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8) function could come in handy.